# I am getting an error code when i try use (member.id)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

my current code is

```py
@client.command()
async def check_vouches(ctx, member : discord.User=None):
  users = await get_vouch_data()
  test = ctx.author
  role = discord.utils.get(test.guild.roles, name="10 vouches")
  vouches_gotten = users[str(member.id)]["vouches_gotten"]
 
if member is not None:
    if vouches_gotten == 10:
    
      await test.add_roles(role)
      await ctx.send("you now have the {role} role")

    else:

      await ctx.reply("first get 10 vouches")
```

which does not give an error code when i start the bot but when i try use the command i get the following error code:

```py
Ignoring exception in command check_vouches:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 193, in check_vouches
    vouches_gotten = users[str(member.id)]["vouches_gotten"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

i have already tried putting

```py
async def check_vouches(ctx, member : discord.User=None,*, id):
```

but when i tried even with an id there it still didn't work. please help me as i am out of ideas as i have tried editing several things and it still gave me an error code

Comment: While you check for `None==member` later, `users[str(member.id)]` tries to use `member` without such protection.

Comment: It should be `if member is not None`, do stuff, if it is None. reply with an error or something

Comment: i changed it to
`@client.command()
async def check_vouches(ctx, member : discord.User=None):
  users = await get_vouch_data()
  test = ctx.author
  role = discord.utils.get(test.guild.roles, name="10 vouches")
  vouches_gotten = users[str(member.id)]["vouches_gotten"]
 
  if member is not None:

    if vouches_gotten == 10:
    
      await test.add_roles(role)
      await ctx.send("you now have the {role} role")

    else:

      await ctx.reply("first get 10 vouches")`
but it still didn't work. also this command is for a person to check their own vouches

Comment: @tevemadar how would i protect it?

Comment: edit your question with the new code, it is hard to read it with comment formatting

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you are only proceeding when the member is None, which shouldn't be the case.
If the member is None, you can do two things, give it a default value and proceed or stop the command and raise an error.

Stopping the command:

```py
if member is None:
    await ctx.send('You have to mention someone to check their vouches')
else:
    # check and show vouch
```

Providing a default value: (author)

```py
if member is None:
    member = ctx.author
# don't check if member is None later
#check and show vouches
```